# Mysql auto-add prefixes to fields

Tags: mysql, sql

Example table1:

```
id | field1 | field2
--------------------
```

table2:

```
id | id1 | field1 | field2
--------------------------
```

Is it possible to do this:

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id1
```

and receive this result:

```
t1_id | t1_fiedl1 | t1_field2 | t2_id | t2_id1 | t2_fiedl1 | t2_field2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The goal is to make mysql auto add prefixes to resulting fields, to avoid long typings, such as

```
select t1.id as t1_id, t1.field1 as t1_field1
```

and so on

Comment: You can get the header, I am not sure about data, please provode sample data and explain what you expect

Comment: I always prefix my field names with a descriptive three letter abbreviation of the table name for all tables.

Comment: Duplicate column names are not a problem in MySQL itself and can be easily fixed in whatever client language you use. I wouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SQL engine will not rewrite your query to "auto-alias" fields for you — aliases must be explicit.

You have two options in client code, however.

First, you could obviously write an abstraction that pieces together the query and provides aliases while doing so.

Second, and easier, is using the information exposed in the underlying [MYSQL_FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-fetch-field.html) structures associated with each result set.  These contain the field and table name (and other information) about each field, allowing you to stitch together `t1_field1` programmatically and without knowing field names in advance.  How this info is exposed depends on your particular client API.

Answer (score 2):

> The goal is to make mysql auto add prefixes to resulting fields, to avoid long typings, such as
>
> `select t1.id as t1_id, t1.field1 as t1_field1 and so on`

If the field names are same on both tables, you will not get columns from both tables.
You have to write column names with specific alias to achieve that.

For e.g.

```
SELECT t1.id t1_id, t1.field1 t1_fiedl1, t1.field2 t1_field2 
      ,t2.id t2_id, t2.id1 t2_id1 ,t2.field1 t2_fiedl1, t2.field2 t2_field2
FROM   table1 t1 
INNER  JOIN table2 t2 
         ON t1.id = t2.id1
```

### [See this SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41895/8)

If Fields name on both tables are different then you can do that to achieve the desired result.

For e.g.

```
SELECT     t1.*, t2.*
FROM       table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t1.id = t2.id1;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b970a/2)

Comment: I know that. But it's really annoying, especially when I operate 3 and more joins on tables with 20+ fields. And what, should I think of synonyms to, say, field `name`, which is used in every table? That's why I'm asking. Maybe there is a more flexible solution.

Comment: The engine always returns *all* fields in the projection.  Client APIs that fetch rows based on the default, unqualified column name, however, won't see multiple fields with the same "name."  SQLFiddle appears use such an API, which is why it cannot distinguish `id` from `id` in you query, but the command line `mysql(1)` client can.

Answer (score 0):

No, mysql does not prefixes the columns *automatically*. The only thing you will do is to manually add an `alias` around the columns. If you don't want to do that, then the best way to do is to rename your columns that makes unique name from each table. If you don't add an `alias`, and there are columns having the same name, the tendency is that the column from the first table will be shown. This is normal because of name collisions between tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
select t1.id as t1_id, t1.fiedl1  as t1_fiedl1 ,
    t1.field2  as t1_field2 ,t2.id as  t2_id , 
     ,t2.fiedl1  as t2_fiedl1 ,t2.field2 as  t2_field2
    from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id1
```

Comment: The point of the question is to be able to select all the fields anonymously and still have the prefix.